# Kafka Structured streaming application throwing IllegalStateException when there is a gap in the offset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Structured Streaming application running with Kafka on spark **2.3**,

The "spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11" version is **2.3.0**

The application starts to read messages and process them successfully, then after reaching a specific offset (as shown in the exception message), it throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tried to fetch 666 but the returned record offset was 665
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer.org$apache$spark$sql$kafka010$InternalKafkaConsumer$$fetchData(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:297)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer$$anonfun$get$1.apply(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer$$anonfun$get$1.apply(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:147)
        at org.apache.spark.util.UninterruptibleThread.runUninterruptibly(UninterruptibleThread.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer.runUninterruptiblyIfPossible(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer.get(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:147)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaDataConsumer$class.get(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaDataConsumer$CachedKafkaDataConsumer.get(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:362)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceRDD$$anon$1.getNext(KafkaSourceRDD.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceRDD$$anon$1.getNext(KafkaSourceRDD.scala:142)
        at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ForeachSink$$anonfun$addBatch$1.apply(ForeachSink.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ForeachSink$$anonfun$addBatch$1.apply(ForeachSink.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:935)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:935)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:381)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It always fail on the same offset, looks like this is due to a gap in the offset, because I saw in Kafka UI that after offset 665 there is 667 (it skipped 666 for some reason), and the Kafka client in my Structured Streaming application tries to fetch 666 and fails.

After digging inside Spark's code, I see that they did not expect this exception to happen (according to the comment):

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.3/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/KafkaDataConsumer.scala#L297

So I am wondering, am I doing something wrong?
Or is this a bug on the specific version I am using?

Comment: It looks like the code you linked to tries to fetch offset 666, but it gets 665 - the lower one, not the higher.

Can you show how kafka consumer is configured?

Comment: Also: Do you have DEBUG log level? Can you see log like "Seeking to $groupId $topicPartition $offset" before the error?

Comment: The Kafka consumer is configured as follows:

("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.P  ..."),

("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "example"),

("startingOffsets", "earliest"),

("subscribe", "the-topic-name"),

("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL"),

("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", "100"),

("kafka.max.partition.fetch.bytes", "2147483647",
("kafka.fetch.message.max.bytes", "2147483647",
("kafka.max.partition.fetch.bytes", "2147483647",
("failOnDataLoss", "false")

Comment: Regarding the:
"Seeking to $groupId $topicPartition $offset"

I have DEBUG level enabled but I don't see any "Seeking into" log

Answer (score 0):

There was a longstanding [issue in Spark](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17147) which was fixed in Spark 2.4, which created a bit of an impedance mismatch between Kafka and Spark.  Part of the fix was backported to Spark 2.3.1, but is only enabled if the configuration option `spark.streaming.kafka.allowNonConsecutiveOffsets` is set to `true`; as you observe, it's quite possible that you're hitting something that wasn't backported, in which case upgrading to Spark 2.4 might be worth considering.

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about "Structured Streaming"? because I think that bug is in "Spark Streaming".

Comment: Structured Streaming uses regular streaming under the hood (see the `KafkaSourceRDD` in the stack trace)... have you tried that configuration option?

Comment: I added this:
sparkSession.conf.set("spark.streaming.kafka.allowNonConsecutiveOffsets", "true")

Before the query, but it did not help.

Actually I saw this bug, it looks related, and it haven't been back ported:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25005